# WMI CPUTemp Always Returns Same Value

Tags: c++, wmi

I'm trying to get my CPU's temperature from WMI. But when i execute code from admin command prompt. It always returns same value;

"**CPU = 39.050000 C**".

I don't know where i've made mistake. My OS is Windows 10 64-bit and I use Visual Studio 2017 15.1 .I wrote same code on C# and it returns same value too just 39. I did some research but I'm still not sure how to approach this.

```
  #define _WIN32_DCOM
    #include <iostream>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    using namespace std;
    #include <comdef.h>
    #include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

HRESULT GetCpuTemperature(LPLONG pTemperature)
{
    if (pTemperature == NULL)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    *pTemperature = -1;
    HRESULT ci = CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IWbemLocator *pLocator;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemAdministrativeLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLocator);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IWbemServices *pServices;
            BSTR ns = SysAllocString(L"root\\WMI");
            hr = pLocator->ConnectServer(ns, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &pServices);
            pLocator->Release();
            SysFreeString(ns);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                BSTR query = SysAllocString(L"SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
                BSTR wql = SysAllocString(L"WQL");
                IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnum;
                hr = pServices->ExecQuery(wql, query, WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY | WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &pEnum);
                SysFreeString(wql);
                SysFreeString(query);
                pServices->Release();
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    IWbemClassObject *pObject;
                    ULONG returned;
                    hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pObject, &returned);
                    pEnum->Release();
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        BSTR temp = SysAllocString(L"CurrentTemperature");
                        VARIANT v;
                        VariantInit(&v);
                        hr = pObject->Get(temp, 0, &v, NULL, NULL);
                        pObject->Release();
                        SysFreeString(temp);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            *pTemperature = V_I4(&v);
                        }
                        VariantClear(&v);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (ci == S_OK)
            {
                CoUninitialize();
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Here is my main code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LONG temp;
    GetCpuTemperature(&temp);
    printf("CPU = %lf °C\n", ((double)temp / 10 - 273.15));
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:Wrong info.

Comment: Does `VARIANT` value have I4 type?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. I'm new in this language. But there is another thing;it returns the same value on C# too but my monitoring program shows different values. Could it be something about my motherboard or etc.?

Comment: `VARIANT` is a structure containing `vt` type flag field and a union. Before accessing the union fields you should check that `vt` is set to corresponding type, `VT_I4` in this case. Using `V_I4` to access I4 field without prior type check may read garbage values. Actually 39 seems like a reasonable value for temperature. Did you run something to rise it up, like WinRAR benchmark?

Comment: I understood your approach but I didn't use any variant structure in my C# code. I'm using Open Hardware Monitor for checking CPU temperature and it shows 59-60 C.I tried other querries on my C# code (Like CPU Usage) and they show different results as they should do.

Comment: I was referring to c++ code, `*pTemperature = V_I4(&v);` line in particular.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,it is none of VARIANT's business, because of this command line in Windows:

```
"wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature"
```

This command needs Administrator role, then you will always see the same values.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my grammar error.Hope to be friends with you.